# NSArray copying after autorelease

Tags: ios, copy, nsarray, autorelease

I am curious on what happen if I have code like this.

```
NSArray* myArray = [NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"a", @"b", @"c", nil];
[myArray autorelease];
myArray = [otherArray copy];
```

`autorelease` would mark the memory to be released at the end of current event loop.

Does that mean `[otherArray copy]` is released at the end of event loop?

Comment: If possible, enable ARC in your project. It will save you a ton of headache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. When you autorelease objects, the *objects* are added to the autorelease pool, not the pointer to those objects. You're autoreleasing an array, if you copy another array into that pointer, it will not be affected.  You should be using ARC anyway, and not using auto/release.

Comment: Yes, I am in process of moving to ARC. Just came across the code so was curious. Thanks